# why using '<< 0' in DirectByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio

I found this code in DirectByteBuffer.java :

```
private long ix(int i) {
    return address + (i << 0);
}
```

Is there any special purpose, or it's same as

```
private long ix(int i) {
    return address + i;
}
```

who can explain, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its exactly the same except it make it clear it has not been shifted.

If you look in ShortBuffer or CharBuffer you might see `<< 1` and in IntBuffer and FloatBuffer `<<2` and in LongBuffer and DoubleBuffer `<< 3`

If you look at the source there is also many blank lines and the formatting suggest the code was generated from a common template which is why `<< 0` was produced.

Comment: The different classes were probably generated from a single template.

Answer (score 0):

If there are other methods that are basically duplicates of `ix` but with different shifts, it could be there for consistency between the methods. Other than that, it's exactly the same as the second method you wrote.